# Jquery validate() is not working properly with additional method

Tags: jquery, validation

Here is my code for the `validation` of registration `form`. But, I am facing problem during run time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#frmRegi").validate({
    rules: {
      firstName: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      lastName: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
          url: AJAX_URL,
          type: "post",
          data: {
            email: function() {
              return $("#email").val();
            },
            action: 'checkEmail',
          }
        },
        email: true,
      },
      password1: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
      },
      cpassword: {
        required: true,
        equalTo: "#password1"
      },
      country: {
        required: true
      },
      state: {
        required: true
      },
      city: {
        required: true
      },
      gen: {
        required: true
      },
      mobile: {
        required: true,
        digitsonly: true,
        minlength: 10
      },
      code: {
        required: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      firstName: {
        required: "Please Enter FirstName"
      },
      lastName: {
        required: "Please Enter Lastname"
      },
      email: {
        required: "Please Enter Your Email address",
        email: "Invalid Email",
        remote: "Email Already Exists"
      },
      password1: {
        required: "Please Enter Password",
        minlength: "Minimum 6 Characters"
      },
      cpassword: {
        required: "Please Re-Enter password",
        equalTo: "passwords doesnt match"
      },
      country: {
        required: "Please select Country"
      },
      state: {
        required: "Please select State"
      },
      city: {
        required: "Please select City"
      },
      gen: {
        required: "please select gender"
      },
      mobile: {
        required: "Please Enter Your Mobile number",
        minlength: "Minimum 10 numbers"
      },
      code: {
        required: "please enter captcha"
      },
    },

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <form name="frmRegi" id="frmRegi" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Tell Us About Yourself... </h3>
      <div class="form-inline">

        <div class="form-group">
          <select>
            <option value="volvo">Mr.</option>
            <option value="saab">Miss.</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name*" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name*" type="text">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-inline full-width-text">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile no.*" type="text">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="3" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline full-width-text">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="gender" name="gen" id="gen">
            <option value="Gender">Gender*</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="secret" id="secret" placeholder="Secret Word" type="text">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control comment" name="paypalEmail" id="paypalEmail" placeholder="Paypal Email" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline full-width-text">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password*" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password*" type="password">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-inline full-width-text">

        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="country" id="country" class="gender">
            <option>aaa</option>
            <option>aaa</option>
            <option>aaa</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="state" id="state" class="gender">
            <option>aaa</option>
            <option>aaa</option>
            <option>aaa</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline full-width-text">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="city" id="city" class="gender">
            <option>aaa</option>
            <option>aaa</option>
            <option>aaa</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <img id="imgCaptcha" src="{SITE_INC}captcha-nct/random.php" class="captcha_img" height="35" alt="Captcha Code" title="Captcha Code" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group refresh">

          <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Enter captcha*" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="submit" name="sbtRegi" id="sbtRegi" class="btn btn-default blue-btn" value="Register" />
        <button type="submit" name="sbtCancel" class="btn btn-default blue-btn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

this code is not working properly.

`validation` is not working on it.

kindly give solution. thanks

Comment: is it giving any errors in console?

Comment: noo errors in console, but the form is getting submited @DharaParmar

Comment: **[`Works fine here`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mh9yvh11/)**?

Comment: yaaa its working from the link which you provided but i dont know whats wrong over here, bdw thanks for you reply @GuruprasadRao

Comment: @Gomzy I have posted answer below..have a look..i hope it will solve your issue

Comment: `AJAX_URL` is not defined + are you sure you included the captcha ressources in your page ?

Comment: @JayeshChitroda its still same problem not working, bdw thanks for your answer

Comment: @PinkTurtle `AJAX_URL` has been defined in another file and yes i have included captcha resource in my code.

Comment: The only way your validation doesn't kick is you have a javascript error on page load so triple check your console for a JS error. Can you provide a link to your live page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points which are creating issue here:

1) add this file below validation file:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

2) In jquery:

```
$("#frmRegi").validate({
            rules:{
                firstName:{required:true,lettersonly: true},
                lastName:{required:true,lettersonly: true},
                email:{ required :true,
                    remote: {
                        url: AJAX_URL,
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            email: function() {
                                return $( "#email" ).val();
                            },
                            action : 'checkEmail',
                        }
                    },
                    email:true,
                },
                password1:{required:true,minlength:6},
                cpassword:{required:true,equalTo:"#password1"},
                country:{required:true},
                state:{required:true},
                city:{required:true},
                gen:{required:true},
                mobile:{required:true,digits: true,minlength:10}, // Change digitsonly to digits
                code:{required:true},
            },
            messages:{
                firstName:{required:"Please Enter FirstName"},
                lastName:{required:"Please Enter Lastname"},
                email:{required:"Please Enter Your Email address",email:"Invalid Email",remote:"Email Already Exists"},
                password1:{required:"Please Enter Password",minlength:"Minimum 6 Characters"},
                cpassword : {required:"Please Re-Enter password",equalTo:"passwords doesnt match"},
                country:{required:"Please select Country"},
                state:{required:"Please select State"},
                city:{required:"Please select City"},
                gen:{required:"please select gender"},
                mobile:{required:"Please Enter Your Mobile number",minlength:"Minimum 10 numbers"},
                code:{required:"please enter captcha"},
            },

        });
```